# bash вывод результата в 2 файла по условию

Tags: bash, консоль

Привет, как записывать вывод исполняемой программы в два файла?

```
echo 'hello world done' >> log.txt | grep 'done' >> detect.txt
```

В первой части кода запись идет постоянно, а во второй только в когда в выводе есть указанная строка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться программой [tee](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) — она умеет дублировать свой *stdin* и в *stdout* и во все указанные параметрами файлы:

```
$ программа | tee -a log.txt | grep done >> detect.txt
```

---

а с помощью программы bash это, конечно, можно осуществить, но, по-моему, выйдет очень громоздко и ресурсозатратно.

Comment: Попробовал Вашу команду, понял что хотел не совсем то что спросил. В итоге нужно записать текст не относящийся к stdout  `echo 'hello world done' >> log.txt | grep 'done'  'text' >> detect.txt` как то так нужно

Comment: *записать текст не относящийся к stdout* — ничего не понял.

Comment: stdout который дает основная программа мы записываем в log.txt, далее чекаем этот же stdout на 'done' (grep 'done') если есть done то записываем 'text' в detect.txt

Comment: так вы описали именно то, что изложено в моём ответе: вам надо получить от некой программы **два одинаковых** потока вывода. один поток записать в файл целиком, а второй «по-grep-ать». если эта ваша некая программа умеет сама дублировать поток, то ничего дополнительного и не нужно. а если не умеет — поможет (например) программа *tee*.

Comment: Ваш пример при обнаружении 'done' записывает полностью вывод, а нужно записать 'text'

Comment: только не «полностью вывод», а лишь те строки, в которых встретилось слово `done`. я думаю, вам лучше будет задать новый вопрос, не забыв уточнить в нём, сколько раз должен быть записан указанный вами текст — один раз на весь запуск конвейера, или по разу для каждой строки, в которой встретится слово `done`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'hello world done' >> log.txt | grep 'done' log.txt >> detect.txt
```

Если в строке есть  `done` то записать идет в оба файла, если нет то только в один

Comment: у вас очень дорогая команд выходит, вначале запись, потом чтение - поиск и запись. При условии что у меня около 30 файлов в секунду пишется - это накладно. Нужно поиск производить в изначальном возврате